# RDLC reports (Microsoft reportViewer) are not rendering when accessed from client machine after deployed to Server

Tags: vb.net, iis, model-view-controller, rdlc, reportviewer

RDLC reports (Microsoft reportViewer) are not rendering after deployed to Server
My rdlc reports are properly rendering and working in development machine(after deployed) when accessed from within the machine itself , it is also working in production server after deployed(when accessed from within the machine itself). However, when I try to access the reports from client machines,  it is not rendering others components of web application are working properly.

the error i am getting is:

google chrome : **failed to load pdf document**

Internet Exploler: **file is damaged and could not be repaired**

How do i fix this error?

my controller code is:

```
        Function GenerateReportS(value As String, lcvalue As String) As ActionResult
        Dim assetlist As List(Of usp_standardreportquery_Result)
        If value IsNot Nothing Or lcvalue IsNot Nothing Then
            assetlist = db.usp_standardreportquery.Where(Function(r) If(value IsNot Nothing, r.AssignLocation = value, True) And
                                                             If(lcvalue IsNot Nothing, r.LocationCategory = lcvalue, True)).ToList
        Else
            assetlist = db.usp_standardreportquery.ToList
        End If

        Dim warnings As Warning()
        Dim mimeType As String
        Dim streamids As String()
        Dim encoding As String
        Dim filenameExtension As String

        Dim viewer = New ReportViewer()
        viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Views\Reports\StandardReport.rdlc"

        Dim dataset As Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource = New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource("standardreportds", assetlist)

        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataset)
        Dim params(2) As ReportParameter
        params(0) = New ReportParameter("SearchBy", "Location", False)
        params(1) = New ReportParameter("value", value, False)
        params(2) = New ReportParameter("Category", lcvalue, False)

        viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(params)

        dataset.Value = assetlist
        viewer.LocalReport.Refresh()

        Dim bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", Nothing, mimeType, encoding, filenameExtension, streamids,
warnings)

        Return New FileContentResult(bytes, mimeType)

        'Return File(bytes, mimeType, "_PackingSlip.pdf")
    End Function
```

how do i fix this error?

Comment: @DeveloperX, can you help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the error "failed to load pdf file" is hard to troubleshoot, After wasting lots of time and searching the web , I solved the issue as fellows

correcting initialization in

```
Dim warnings As Warning()
Dim streamids As String()
Dim mimeType As String = "application/pdf"
Dim encoding As String = String.Empty
Dim filenameExtension As String = String.Empty
```

and finally inserting the following code after `Dim bytes =`

```
Response.Buffer = True
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = mimeType
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
Response.Flush()
```